# How to make key and array change together?

Tags: php, arrays, key

```
<?php 
    $test = array("a" => "horse","b" => "fish");
    $k = array_keys($test);
    print_r($k);
    unset($test["a"]);
    print_r($test);
    print_r($k);
?>
```

I have changed `array("a" => "horse","b" => "fish")` into `array("b" => "fish")` with `unset function ;` the `$k` unchanged.

How make the key in the array and array itself change together?
To change the `$k` into:

```
Array
(
    [0] => b
)
```

**Not:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => a
    [1] => b
)
```

Answer (score 1):

What I've understand from your question then you can simply use `array_intersect` as

```
$test = array("a" => "horse", "b" => "fish");
$k = array_keys($test);
unset($test["a"]);
$k = array_intersect(array_keys($test), $k);
print_r($k);
```